GKE tries to reserve static IP that already exists which results in ERRORS
We are encountering a constant errors about creation of the static IP address.
What we've done is:

With the usage of Terraform we have reserved a static IP address.
Then we have deployed the emissary ingress onto our GKE cluster.
As instructed in the dcocs
we've set the spec.loadBalancerIP to the IP reserved by Terraform.

After that, every 10 minutes, we noticed that GKE is trying to reserve the exact same IP address that we defined in the service and fails with the following error:
Invalid value for field 'resource.address': '<IP-ADDRESS>'. Specified IP address is already reserved.

When I deleted the service the errors stopped.
Currently we are running version 1.29.9-gke.1496000, but the first time we noticed the error was in ~June and from that time, we've upgraded version of the control plane, so I'm not sure the version is an issue in that case.
I am attaching the full log from the GCP Logs Explorer in the JSON format with all the sensitive values redacted.
Besides that, everything is working as expected. Forwarding rules and backends are created correctly, traffic is passing through - all good. The only issue is that we are getting ERROR entries in the logs.
{
    "protoPayload": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
      "status": {
        "code": 3,
        "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource.address': '<RESERVED-IP>'. Specified IP address is already reserved."
      },
      "authenticationInfo": {
        "principalEmail": "service-<PROJECT-NUMBER>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "principalSubject": "serviceAccount:service-<PROJECT-NUMBER>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      },
      "requestMetadata": {
        "callerIp": "34.91.169.220",
        "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "google-api-go-client/0.5 Kubernetes/0.0.0 (linux amd64),gzip(gfe)",
        "requestAttributes": {
          "time": "2024-11-30T13:54:57.570604Z",
          "auth": {}
        },
        "destinationAttributes": {}
      },
      "serviceName": "compute.googleapis.com",
      "methodName": "v1.compute.addresses.insert",
      "authorizationInfo": [
        {
          "resource": "projects/<PROJECT-ID>/regions/europe-west4/addresses/<ADDRESS-ID>",
          "permission": "compute.addresses.create",
          "granted": true,
          "resourceAttributes": {
            "service": "compute",
            "name": "projects/<PROJECT-ID>/regions/europe-west4/addresses/<ADDRESS-ID>",
            "type": "compute.addresses"
          },
          "permissionType": "ADMIN_WRITE"
        }
      ],
      "resourceName": "projects/<PROJECT-ID>/regions/europe-west4/addresses/<ADDRESS-ID>",
      "request": {
        "addressType": "EXTERNAL",
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/compute.addresses.insert",
        "description": "{\"kubernetes.io/service-name\":\"emissary/emissary-ingress\"}",
        "address": "<RESERVED-IP>",
        "name": "<ADDRESS-ID>",
        "networkTier": "PREMIUM"
      },
      "response": {
        "error": {
          "errors": [
            {
              "domain": "global",
              "reason": "invalid",
              "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource.address': '<RESERVED-IP>'. Specified IP address is already reserved."
            }
          ],
          "code": 400,
          "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource.address': '<RESERVED-IP>'. Specified IP address is already reserved."
        },
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/error"
      },
      "resourceLocation": {
        "currentLocations": [
          "europe-west4"
        ]
      }
    },
    "insertId": "-tmww84ef5tuc",
    "resource": {
      "type": "gce_reserved_address",
      "labels": {
        "location": "europe-west4",
        "reserved_address_id": "",
        "project_id": "<PROJECT-ID>"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2024-11-30T13:54:57.331731Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "compute.googleapis.com/root_trigger_id": "4be0d0ce-ad68-4b10-9480-a0d9c2648ef5"
    },
    "logName": "projects/<PROJECT-ID>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2024-11-30T13:54:57.602602513Z"
  }

Also posted at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/381518936

Unfamiliar with Emissary Ingress but if your GKE Service has type loadBalancer and a public IP, it will result in a TCP Load-balancer being programmed by Google Cloud. I think Emissary is going to want the IP address and so the GKE Service should omit both this (IP) binding and type: loadBalancer so that Emissary can use it.

I'm not sure if I understood correctly. In our setup, we have one service of a type LoadBalancer that emissary ingress is using. Then we're setting the IP as instructed in the google docs

Let me try to answer with an example: (1) Q="79244432"; kubectl create namespace {${Q}; kubectl create deployment kuard  --image=gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue --namespace=${Q} --port=8080;  kubectl expose deployment/kuard --namespace=${Q} --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 after ~minute then kubectl get service/kuard --namespace=${Q} --output=jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}" will match kubectl get service/kuard --namespace=${Q} --output=jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}".

When you create a GKE Service of type: loadBalancer, you program Google Cloud to create a Google (!) L4 load-balancer (aka forwarding rule) that uses a public IP.

Yes, I am aware of that, but in our case the order is different. You created a LoadBalancer first and then allowed GCP to allocate random IP. In our case we already have the static IP, and according to the docs if you want to use already defined static IP address you must define it in the loadBalancer.spec.loadBalancerIP. And by doing so, we get the errors

Because I don't have a static IP address. The point is that, by specifying type: loadBalancer (with|without an IP address) Google Cloud programs an L4 load-balancer. Once the IP is bound to that, you can't then use it to program another ingress using Emissary. Good luck!
